# Implementing iOS procotol - readonly property

Tags: ios

I have a protocol from QuickLook framework:

```
/*!
 * @abstract The QLPreviewItem protocol declares the methods that a QLPreviewController  instance uses to access the contents of a given item.
 */
@protocol QLPreviewItem <NSObject>

@required

/*!
 * @abstract The URL of the item to preview.
 * @discussion The URL must be a file URL. 
 */
@property(readonly) NSURL * previewItemURL;

@optional

/*!
 * @abstract The item's title this will be used as apparent item title.
 * @discussion The title replaces the default item display name. This property is optional.
 */
@property(readonly) NSString * previewItemTitle;


@end

/*!
 * @abstract This category makes NSURL instances as suitable items for the Preview Controller.
 */
@interface NSURL (QLPreviewConvenienceAdditions) <QLPreviewItem>
@end
```

I'm trying to create the getter and setter for the readonly property previewItemTitle so I can add my custom tile:

.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <QuickLook/QuickLook.h>

@interface QLPreviewItemCustom : NSObject <QLPreviewItem> {
    NSURL * previewItemURL;
    NSString *previewItemTitle;
}


@property(readonly) NSURL * previewItemURL;
@property (readonly) NSString *previewItemTitle;


@end
```

.m

```
#import "QLPreviewItemCustom.h"


@implementation QLPreviewItemCustom

@synthesize previewItemTitle;
@synthesize previewItemURL;


@end
```

This way, as I understand, I will create just the getter with the synthesize method. How can I create the setter?

Comment: Why do you need setter for readonly property?

Comment: Because this is what the documentation of Quick Look framework says to do, when you need to set a custom title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's just in your implementation of `QLPreviewItemCustom` that you want to access the setter, then why not extend the property in a class continuation category to read-write:

QLPreviewItemCustom.m

```
#import "QLPreviewItemCustom.h"

@interface QLPreviewItemCustom ()

@property (readwrite) NSURL *previewItemURL;
@property (readwrite) NSString *previewItemTitle;

@end

@implementation QLPreviewItemCustom

@synthesize previewItemTitle;
@synthesize previewItemURL;

@end
```

If you want to use the setter everywhere then you'll have to use a different ivar name and write your getter for the original to pass through to your new one. Like this:

QLPreviewItemCustom.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <QuickLook/QuickLook.h>

@interface QLPreviewItemCustom : NSObject <QLPreviewItem> {
    NSURL *url;
    NSString *title;
}


@property (readwrite) NSURL *url;
@property (readwrite) NSString *title;

@end
```

QLPreviewItemCustom.m

```
#import "QLPreviewItemCustom.h"

@implementation QLPreviewItemCustom

@synthesize url;
@synthesize title;

- (NSURL*)previewItemURL {
    return self.url;
}

- (NSString*)previewItemTitle {
    return self.title;
}

@end
```

It's worth also pointing out that it's not generally a good idea to use the same class prefix yourself as is used by another framework. i.e. don't call it `QLPreviewItemCustom` - call it something like `ABCPreviewItemCustom`.

Comment: I need to access it from outside the class. The PreviewControllerClass.previewItemTitle returns the QLPreviewItem object. Than I make QLPreviewItemCustom *title = PreviewControllerClass.previewItemTitle. And then I want to set the previewItemTitle, but first I need to create that setter correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I'm probably asking the wrong questions 'cause I'm new at iOS programming. The attribute previewItemTitle is defined readonly in the protocol, and if I declare it differently I get warnings. So basically my question is: How can I implement a framework protocol that has a readonly attribute in a way that I make that attribute writable too?

Answer (score 1):

You can write to it directly in variable, not in property. If you write self.previewItemURL you'll access property, but if you write just previewItemURL you'll access variable and you can write to it without any restrictions.

For more visibility you can name your field differently, for example

```
@interface QLPreviewItemCustom : NSObject <QLPreviewItem> {
    NSURL * _previewItemURL;
    NSString *_previewItemTitle;
}


@property(readonly) NSURL * previewItemURL;
@property (readonly) NSString *previewItemTitle;


@end
```

and implementation:

```
@implementation QLPreviewItemCustom

@synthesize previewItemTitle = _previewItemTitle;
@synthesize previewItemURL = _previewItemURL;

@end
```

Now, you can access field directly via `_Name` and property as `self.Name`